# Can you check if a stored procedure parameter contains a string value?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to be able to check if a parameter contains a particular word.

For example:

```
@ContactName VARCHAR(50)

IF CONTAINS(@ContactName, 'Temp')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if CHARINDEX('Temp',@ContactName) > 0
```

CHARINDEX()
This function is used to search for a specific word or a substring in an overall string and returns its starting position of match. In case no word is found, then it will return 0 (zero).

Comment: Add an explanation to what this does for the OP, so that they can understand the answer.